# Call method from other class

Tags: android, class, methods

Ok I am a complete newb when it comes to java classes. I have a public method that dynamically displays some Linearlayouts with some stuff in them. For instance this method (public void methodA)is in ClassA.java, then I want to call methodA from inside ClassB.java. Both of the classes extend Activity and the methodA is being called in the OnCreate method.

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        methodA();
    }
    public void methodA() {
        //Do Stuff
        /* This uses:
        * Package Manager 
        * Buttons using(this)
        * Linear Layouts using(this)
        * TextViews using(this)
        * findViewById()
        * startActivity
        */
    }

}
```

ClassB.java

```
public class ClassB extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        methodA(); //How do I do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear to me that the method is specific to the first activity, which means that it shouldn't be called in the second one. You can either reimplement the method in the second activity or, if these activities are similar (*don't do this if they aren't!*), you have two options:

- Inherit the second activity from the first one.
- Merge these two activities into one and use different intents to launch them and act accordingly.

The second method is easier to maintain, so I would prefer it over the first one in simpler cases.

Comment: Why we can't get reference to another activity?

Comment: @TarunDroid Android manages activities itself, it doesn't provide any way to get it because it's against Android design. Of course, you can create instantiate the class of the activity yourself, but there's little point in that.

Comment: I added in some detail to what is called within the method, if it is not enough detail please say and I will provide :)

Comment: @Nicholas Rewrote the answer completely.

Answer (score 0):

Craete instance of class A in class B and then you can invoke MethodA from class B

public class ClassB extends Activity{

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //MethodA(); //How do I do this
    ClassA  a=new ClassA ();
    a.MethodA();
}
```

}